# Simple Conditional Expectation Problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

$$Y := \begin{cases} \begin{matrix} 5 & \text{w.p. } \frac{1}{5} \\ 2 & \text{w.p. } \frac{1}{2} \\ 1 & \text{w.p. } \frac{3}{10} \end{matrix} \end{cases}$$ *Note:* $\text{w.p.}$ stands for "with probability". If $A$ is the event that $Y = 2$ or $Y=5$, how do I find $\mathbb{E}[Y|A]$?

Comment: First work out $P(Y = 2\mid A) = \frac{P(Y=2)}{P(A)}$ and $P(Y=5\mid A) = \frac{P(Y=5)}{P(A)}$.  (Hint: the two conditional probabilities should sum to $1$. Then, apply the formula for conditional expectation.